# How can the main function gets its argument when we run a program on eclipse?

Tags: java, cmd, program-entry-point

I have this question but could not figure it out. when we invoke a program on the cmd we pass command line arguments to the main function. what happen if we run it on eclipse? is there anyway that eclipse do? or the compiler?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click, "Run As > Run Configuration". Click on the arguments tab, fill in the "Program Arguments" text box and then click "Run";

[image: eclipse - Run Configuration - Program Arguments]

Answer (score 2):

`Run` -> `Run Configurations...` -> `Arguments`

[image]